# How do I pass multiple elements into a React component

Tags: reactjs, components

It only passes the first element (element1) into the render function but the others don't work? I don't really understand how this is supposed to work.

```
class ContactCard extends React.Component {

    render(){
        return <h1> Name: {this.props.name}  
        Mobile Phone: {this.props.num}  
        Work Phone: {this.props.work}</h1>
    }
}

const element1 = <ContactCard name="Mary" />;
const element2 = <ContactCard num="9176030350" />;
const element3 = <ContactCard work="2176012130" />;

ReactDOM.render(
    element1, 
     document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added some code and comments to help you understand. The issue is that you've created 3 elements with 1 prop instead of 1 element with 3 props.

`element` is given a `name` property, but it isn't supplied with `num` or `work` properties. As a result, only the name is rendered. A similar issue exists for `element2` and `element3`. We can resolve this by giving a single element (`element4`) all of the properties.

```
class ContactCard extends React.Component {

    render(){
        return <h1> Name: {this.props.name}  
        Mobile Phone: {this.props.num}  
        Work Phone: {this.props.work}</h1>
    }
}

// these all only receive one prop
const element1 = <ContactCard name="Mary" />;
const element2 = <ContactCard num="9176030350" />;
const element3 = <ContactCard work="2176012130" />;
// all three elements above can be removed and element4 will still work

// this will receive all three
const element4 = <ContactCard name="Mary" num="9176030350" work="2176012130" />;

ReactDOM.render(
    // render element4 because it has all the props
    element4, 
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

If you wanted to render all the elements that you've created, you'd need to create a parent element that contains all of them and pass the parent element to `ReactDOM.render`. Here is an example:

```
const parentWithChildren = (
  <div>
    <ContactCard name="Mary" num="9176030350" work="2176012130" />
    <ContactCard name="Mary" num="9176030350" work="2176012130" />
  <div>
)

ReactDom.render(
  parentWithChildren,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass multiple variables you need to pass all props like attributes.

In the example below, you can see `<ContactCard name="Mary" num="9176030350" work="2176012130" />`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class ContactCard extends React.Component {

    render(){
        return (<h1> Name: {this.props.name}  
        Mobile Phone: {this.props.num}  
        Work Phone: {this.props.work} </h1>)
    }
}
const element = <ContactCard name="Mary" num="9176030350" work="2176012130" />

ReactDOM.render( element , document.getElementById('root'));
```